# any Cocoa control code that I can use that acts as a patch bay?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, custom-controls, nsview

I would like to make a patch bay type control...  any source online that anyone knows of that I could work from?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_panel

Comment: Looks similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559168 (which also suggests EFLaceView)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest thing I'm aware of is EFLaceView: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?FlowChartView

Edit: EFLaceView seems to have disappeared, but I have a saved copy: [EFLaceView](http://files.sbooth.org/EFLaceView.zip)

Edit: Version of [EFLaceView on github](https://github.com/danielkleinert/EFLaceView/), with more recent changes than link above.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the links on the CocoaDev page work anymore.  :(  Do you have the dmg downloaded and could you post it somewhere?  I'd love to take a look at it.

Comment: No problem- I had a local copy and I've uploaded it to my site. The link is above.

Comment: +1 that is a really slick piece of code! That's definitely going in my "Must Save" folder. :)

Comment: note, the newer version has a bug that crashes the app when multiple inputs or outputs are added to a node. no idea how to fix it, but the older version seems to work fine.

Comment: @miketucker this is true for the example app. The framework has no issues with multiple inputs/outputs though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can find someone online who is sharing exactly the kind of control you're looking for, you don't have any choice but to build this for yourself. For that, you need to understand [Control and Cell Programming](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html), [Cocoa Drawing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), and create your own [custom view](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html).