# Graph view like iAd producer

Tags: cocoa, graph, iad

Is there a way to use the same tree graph component as Apple uses for iAd producer? An equivalent would be fine, but if it's already in the cocoa framework, can somebody point to the specific component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There's a framework for iPhone and Mac called Core Plot, [available on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).  However, if you're looking to put graphs in the iAd itself, you'd need to find a Javascript-based framework.</strike>

Ah, you're looking for a visual layout control.  Sorry, the only thing I know of like that is "EFLaceView", but there's no reliable download link to it anywhere.  If you google it, you might find it.  EFLaceView is a bit different from what's shown in the screenshot (it's more like what you see in Quartz Composer), but it's pretty similar.

Edit:  Aha, there's a link to it here: [any Cocoa control code that I can use that acts as a patch bay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3071832/115730)