# How to design an application with QuartzComposer-like GUI

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, custom-controls, core-graphics

I'm planning to write a relatively simple app for building database-like schemas. The goal is to build an usable tool and exercise Cocoa programming.
The main component of this app would be a view that lets user to place draggable boxes with editable lists inside and then link them with lines. I'm sure You know what I'm thinking of.

It could look a bit like this thing:
[image: QuartzComposer gui example]

The problem is I don't know what would be the best approach in this case. Should I:

1. Subclass NSView and write a huuge view that manages rendering of the boxes, connections, handles all events, etc. or...
2. Write views for boxes and then use some (unknown to me) infrastructure to manage and display them, or...
3. Use something that does what I want and someone wrote it already (cannot find anything), or...
4. Something else (??)

1 and 2 are for sure doable but I want to do it the proper way. I think it would be cool to reuse some ready Cocoa controls inside of the boxes.

I'm experienced programmer but quite new to Cocoa and Objective-C.

And how would You do that? Any hints and ideas highly appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [any Cocoa control code that I can use that acts as a patch bay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071832/any-cocoa-control-code-that-i-can-use-that-acts-as-a-patch-bay)

Comment: The difference is that I know that there aren't any controls that act as a patch bay. I wan't to design and code one :)

Comment: there's an answer to the linked question that includes a download to one called "EFLaceView" that is a rudimentary patch bay.

Comment: Thanks. I just downloaded it but somehow I don't like it. Also it relies on Core Data, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each box would likely be an custom, subclassed, NSView. BoxView perhaps.
Then you'd have a view controller for the view that contains the boxes.
That view controller will handle moving the boxes around and that kind of stuff.
The boxes will be added to the view controller's view as subviews.
That's the approach I would take anyway.

Comment: What do You think about subclassing NSView as in approach (1) and representing each box as a CALayer? Would it be a pain to put regular controls in there?

Comment: @nooga I wouldn't make each box a `CALayer`, mainly since `CALayer`s don't support user interaction, and are purely graphical.

Comment: @spudwaffle The parent control would handle the interaction... but that'd be huge and probably wrong! But I think there would be problems with drawing connection lines if I used Randall's approach.

Comment: You should still be able to draw lines just fine with each box as an NSView. The view controller will know where all the boxes are, so it shouldn't have a problem knowing where to draw the lines either.

Answer (score 1):

I've read comments and answers, did some research and came up with such design. Check out the mockup below:

[image: my design]

Does it look sane?

Comment: As the number of nodes grows, I wonder what's the smartest way to optimize the redraws of connectors (`ComposerView.draw(_:)`) smoothly as one node gets dragged.

Comment: Also, what kind of algorithms are there available to minimize the "connector mess" (perhaps minimize length? Something like what Interface Builder does with segues perhaps...?)